# Best Practices in Protecting Amazon S3 Files?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, access-control

For example, I have a website with User A and B.
Both of them can login to my website using my own login system.

How do I make certain files from S3 accessible only to User A once he login to my website?

Note: I saw "Permission" in AWS Management Console with "Authenticated Users" option but it seems that it's meant for other S3 users only, is it something I can use to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Amazon IAM - you can define what part of any S3 bucket A can see, as well as B and each will not have access to do 'anything'. In general you should never use the account ID and secret for anything, always make an IAM user have just whats needed to run your stuff. The admin user likely does not need EC2 or SQS, or SimpleDB, etc.

Federated access is great for allowing arbitrary users to sign into your website and only be granted access for say 12 hours. They get special AWSIDs for that access that will work only on the section of S3 you let them look at.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but do I really need to create users inside AWS? I've read somewhere that expiring URLs should do the job, is that related to IAM or completely different? I am having the impression that I don't really need to create users inside AWS.

To be clear: I just need to let my users download files assigned to them from my website only when they're logged-in to my website (they don't need to have user accounts in AWS).

Comment: Federated access is sort of like expiring URLs but for any part of an s3 repo that you choose. The federated token thing was built for the kind of use you describe - you build a set of id + secret + token for every person who logs in, based on what you want to allow them to do. Then - even if the user tries to hack into another area on S3 using some hole in your UI/server/etc - it won't work as they only have the access you granted when you called GetFederatedToken.

Comment: But won't users be allowed to share the urls until they expire? - any way to prevent this?